# CSS background image is not responsive in a browser on a real smartphone

Tags: html, css, image, background, responsive

I have CSS like below, when tested in a PC browser it was responsive, I already tested with responsive design mode its normal, but when I tested on my phone, the background was not responsive:

```
.imgBG {
  background: url(../../../assets/img/bg-img/bg-login-blur.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  padding:20px;
 }
```

[image]

What am I missing, could you please advise me?

Comment: What do you mean that it is not responsive?

Comment: Yes . My Background image not responsive when i test it in smartphone

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your HTML header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

**add this line to code** : `background-attachment: fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
 .imgBG { 
    background-image: url(../../../assets/img/bg-img/bg-login-blur.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Already try this.. not fixed in smartphone, but i test in PC with maximize/minimize its work